# How to set the "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol" header in python websocket server handshake response?

Tags: python, node.js, websocket, handshake

I have a python websocket server and a nodejs client and I am not able
to implement the [websocket's Protocol Handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Protocol_handshake).

#### Code of python server

The following minimal websocket server makes use of `Flask-sockets`
(which uses `gevent-websocket`). File name is `ws_server.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, request, Response
from flask_sockets import Sockets

app = Flask(__name__)
sockets = Sockets(app)

@sockets.route('/')
def echo_socket(ws):
    # print("type request: ",type(request))
    # print("dir  request: ", dir(request))
    print("request.headers: ", request.headers)
    # print("type ws: ",type(ws))
    # print("dir  ws: ",dir(ws))

    if hasattr(request, "Sec-Websocket-Protocol"):
        print(request.headers["Sec-Websocket-Protocol"])
    else:
        print("INFO: No protocol specified")

    if request.headers["Sec-Websocket-Protocol"] == "aProtocol":
        print("INFO: protocol is OK")
    else:
        print("INFO: protocol not accepted: closing connection")
        ws.close()

    while not ws.closed:
        message = ws.receive()
        if message:
            print("received: "+message)
            ws.send(message)

    if ws.closed:
        print("INFO: connection has been closed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from gevent import pywsgi
    from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
    server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('', 5001), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

#### Code of nodejs client

The following minimal websocket client makes use of `websocket`
library.
File name is `app.js`:

```
'use strict'

var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;
var client = new WebSocketClient();

function connectToServer(uri,protocol){
    client.on('connectFailed', function (error) {
        console.log('Connect Error: ' + error.toString());
    });

    client.on('connect', function (connection) {
        console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');

        connection.on('error', function (error) {
            console.log("Connection Error: " + error.toString());
        });

        connection.on('close', function () {
            console.log('echo-protocol Connection Closed');
        });

        connection.on('ping', () => {
            connection.pong();
        });

        connection.on('message', function (message) {
            if (message.type === 'utf8') {
                console.log("Received message is: '" + message.utf8Data + "'");
            }
        });
        console.log("sending SOMETHING");
        connection.sendUTF("SOMETHING");
    });
    client.connect(uri, protocol);
}

const wsHostAndPort = process.env.WSHSTPRT || "ws://echo.websocket.org:80";
const wsProtocol = process.env.WSPRTCL || []; // [] for no protocol

console.log("connecting to: ",wsHostAndPort,"with protocol",wsProtocol);
connectToServer(wsHostAndPort,wsProtocol);
```

#### Connection from nodejs as client

Start python ws server:

```
$ python3 ws_server.py
```

Connect from nodejs ws client:

```
$ WSHSTPRT=ws://localhost:5001/ WSPRTCL="aProtocol" node app.js
```

Output of client terminal is

```
connecting to:  ws://localhost:5001/ with protocol aProtocol
Connect Error: Error: Expected a Sec-WebSocket-Protocol header.
```

Output of server terminal is:

```
request.headers:  Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-Websocket-Version: 13
Sec-Websocket-Key: +QjH5xejDI+OQZQ0OZcWEQ==
Host: localhost:5001
Sec-Websocket-Protocol: aProtocol


INFO: No protocol specified
INFO: protocol is OK
INFO: connection has been closed
```

It seems to me that the python server needs to set a header named
`"Sec-WebSocket-Protocol"` with the same value it has received from the
client. But I don't know how to do it.  I have searched the internet
(mainly the `flask-sockets` and `gevent-websockets` forums and issue
trackers) without any luck so far.

I tried another simple client, `websocat`. I invoked it like this:
`$ websocat ws://localhost:5001 --protocol aProtocol`
I interactively prompted some messages, and they were echoed correctly by the python server.
It works because, i think, `websocat` (unlike nodejs' `websocket`) does
not expect a "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol header" in the handshake with the
server.

But I need to use the nodejs client which expects the header.
So my question is: how can I incorporate the `"Sec-WebSocket-Protocol"`
header in the python server handshake response?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: No luck unfortunately. Also, I am migrating my server-side software to nodejs.

Answer (score 3):

I know this was over a year ago and it looks like you've moved on, though it looks like you were almost there, just `aProtocol` needed to be replaced with the [`subprotocol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Protocol_upgrade_mechanism#Sec-WebSocket-Protocol) that the server expects.

Or alternately, omitted entirely as per the underlying [gevent-websocket](https://gitlab.com/noppo/gevent-websocket/-/blob/master/docs/index.rst) that [flask-websockets uses](https://github.com/heroku-python/flask-sockets/blob/003660b70bbe16e218fb8b28377603e86e9d1b36/setup.py#L28):

```
// Subprotocol (2nd parameter) often is not required at all
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:5001/api');
```

---

For future me or anyone else who stumbles here, I hope the following helps.

In JavaScript connecting a browser to the Node.JS [apollo-server subscriptions](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/#client-setup), I needed the following:

```
// Pasted into Firefox console
const token = '...';  // A bearer token, if auth is needed
const subprotocol = 'graphql-ws';
w = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:5000/graphql', subprotocol);
w.send(JSON.stringify({"type":"connection_init","payload":{"authToken":token}}));
```

Then I'd see `Sec-Websocket-Protocol` header applied:
[image: Sec-Websocket-Protocol header]
[image: Message sent and ack received]

Otherwise if no subprotocol is applied, `Sec-Websocket-Protocol` header not sent and Control messages visible, I'd see [`Connection Closed: 1002`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.4.1) and naturally be unable to send messages to the websocket:

[image: Connection Closed: 1002]